# Javascript function to find the mode of a list of numbers

Tags: javascript

```js
 function findMode(list) {
  var maxIndex = 0;
  var newIndex = 0;
  var number = 0;
  var mode = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    number = list[i];
    for (var x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {
      if (number == list[x]) {
        newIndex++;
      }
      console.log((number + "=") + newIndex);
    }
    if (newIndex > maxIndex) {
      maxIndex = newIndex;
      mode = number;
      newIndex = 0;
    } else {
      newIndex = 0;
    }
  }
  console.log(mode);
  return mode;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="findMode([1,2,6,4,6,5])">Check</button>
```

The code above is supposed to find the mode (most common number) and set it to the `var mode`. For some reason it isn't working is there something I can do to fix this.

Comment: Can you provide an input where this function fails?

Comment: Looks ok to me. Can you be more specific than "it isn't working"?

Comment: nvm agian thank you

Comment: why not just count the numbers with an object?

Comment: @Fuzzionkiller You can simply create a Map where you can store elements and their frequencies and then find out the element with the maximum frequency. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single loop with an object fro counting and store the max count along with the values.

```js
function findMode(list) {
    var max = -Number.MAX_VALUE,
        mode = [],
        count = {};

    for (const value of list) {
        count[value] = (count[value] || 0) + 1;
        if (count[value] > max) {
            max = count[value];
            mode = [value];
            continue;
        }
        if (count[value] === max) {
            mode.push(value);        
        }
    }
    return mode;
}

console.log(findMode([7, 1, 2, 6, 4, 6, 5, 7]));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Reduce the `list` into a `Map` whose keys represent the `list` items and values represent the frequency of these items.
2. Then find the key in the `Map` that has the maximum value (or frequency).

```js
function findMode(list) {
  const mode = Array.from(
    list.reduce((m, el) => m.set(el, (m.get(el) || 0) + 1), new Map())
  ).reduce((r, [k, v]) => (v > r[1] ? [k, v] : r), [null, 0])[0];

  console.log("Mode:", mode);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="findMode([1,2,6,4,6,5])">Check [1,2,6,4,6,5]</button>

<button onclick="findMode([1,2,2,4,6,2])">Check [1,2,2,4,6,2]</button>

<button onclick="findMode([5,5,2,4,6,2,5,3])">Check [5,5,2,4,6,2,5,3]</button>
```